# Accessing members of an object that hasn't been initialized?

Tags: c++, objective-c

I'm not very familiar with C++ programming. I know the basics of programming in it (syntax, pointers, etc.) and I've built a few basic programs with it and done some basic debugging at work. I am puzzled by this line of code from Box2D, specifically the Box2dTest project from Cocos2D:

```
// Define the ground body.
b2BodyDef groundBodyDef;
groundBodyDef.position.Set(0, 0); // bottom-left corner
```

How is it that one can do this without having initialized `groundBodyDef`? I know this isn't an Objective-C thing because the C++ examples for Box2D itself are just like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`groundBodyDef` actually is initialized!

I think you expected something along the lines of:

```
b2BodyDef *groundBodyDef = new b2BodyDef();
```

which is actually still valid, but it is initialized on the heap. In your version, `groundBodyDef` is initialized on the stack, much like you would initialize an `int` on the stack.

As it is called without parameters, the default constructor is used.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I was expecting. I typically program in C# and sometimes Java.

Answer (score 2):

The object has been initialized by its constructor on the first line.

I would recommend the following link, which is a very good text on C++: [The C++ Annotations](http://www.icce.rug.nl/documents/cplusplus/).

Comment: I'll read that thanks! I'm coming from Java and C#, where the convention for initialization is: `MyObject foo = new MyObject();`

Comment: That's right, in C# those objects are always treated as reference, which is only the case in C++ when using pointers. In general, you have to control the life of your objects in C++ whereas it is done automatically in C#. You will find a good overview of the difference between both languages here: media.wiley.com/assets/264/22/0764557599_bonus_AppD.pdf

Answer (score 2):

If `b2BodyDef` has a decent default constructor, then the part about "without having initialized" just doesn't apply -- the default ctor HAS initialized `groundBodyDef`!

Answer (score 1):

If you do `classname variable;` then `variable` will be initalized by calling the default constructor of `classname`, meaning there is no unitialized variable in your code.